# Stackoverflow exception (Recursion) for typical 1-to-n relationship

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, relationships

[image]

This is my Car class:

```
public class Car {
private int FGNr;
private String name;
private String type;
private Owner owner;

private static ArrayList<Integer> allCarIds = new ArrayList<>();

public Car(int FGNr, String name, String type, Owner o) throws Exception {
    setFGNr(FGNr);
    setName(name);
    setType(type);
    setOwner(o);
}



public int getFGNr() {
    return FGNr;
}


public void setFGNr(int FGNr) throws Exception{
    this.FGNr = FGNr;
    if(allCarIds.contains(this.FGNr))
        throw new Exception("FGNr already excists!! ");
     allCarIds.add(this.FGNr);}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Owner getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(Owner owner) throws Exception{ 
    owner.addCar(this);
    this.owner = owner;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 73 * hash + this.FGNr;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Car other = (Car) obj;
    if (this.FGNr != other.FGNr) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Car{" + "FGNr=" + FGNr + ", name=" + name + ", type=" + type + ", owner=" + owner + '}';
  }   
}
```

And this is my Owner class:

```
public class Owner {
private String SVNr;
private String name;
HashSet<Car> allCars = new HashSet<>();
private static ArrayList<String> allOwnerSVNs = new ArrayList<>();

public Owner(String SVNr, String name) throws Exception{
    setSVNr(SVNr);
    setName(name);
}

public void addCar(Car c) throws Exception{
    if(allCars.contains(c))
        throw new Exception("this user has already this car");
    if(c.getOwner()!=null)
        throw new Exception("this car belongs to other owner");

    c.setOwner(this);
    allCars.add(c);
}

public String getSVNr() {
    return SVNr;
}

public void setSVNr(String SVNr) throws Exception{
    this.SVNr = SVNr;
     if(allOwnerSVNs.contains(this.SVNr))
        throw new Exception("SVNg already excists!! ");
     allOwnerSVNs.add(this.SVNr);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public HashSet<Car> getAllCars() {
    return allCars;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.SVNr);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Owner other = (Owner) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.SVNr, other.SVNr)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Owner{" + "SVNr=" + SVNr + ", name=" + name + ", allCars=" + allCars + '}';
    }    
}
```

And this is my main:

```
 try {
        Owner o1 = new Owner("0001","Owner1");
        Owner o2 = new Owner("0002","Owner2");

        Car c1 = new Car(1,"Model S", "Tesla",o1);
        Car c2 = new Car(2,"Model 3", "Tesla",o2);
        Car c3 = new Car(3,"TT", "Audi",o2);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error:"+ex.getMessage());

    }
```

So when trying to create a new Car I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:595)
at java.util.HashSet.contains(HashSet.java:203)
at pkgData.Owner.addCar(Owner.java:28)
at pkgData.Car.setOwner(Car.java:63)
```

...........

It is a recursion error, but I don't know how to fix it. If I create a new car obviously I have to add the Car to the owner arrayList of cars. and if I call the addCar function the function calls the getOwner function. It's an endless circle of calling.

How I can make sure that when creating a new car that the collection of the owner will also be changed. It would not make any sense that a car has an owner but the owner of the car does not the car in his collection.

Comment: read careful code, there is obvious call addWoner in two places of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two functions fall an infinite loop as you see.

In Car class

```
public void setOwner(Owner owner) throws Exception{ 
    owner.addCar(this);
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

And in Owner Class

```
public void addCar(Car c) throws Exception{
    if(allCars.contains(c))
        throw new Exception("this user has already this car");
    if(c.getOwner()!=this && c.getOwner()!=null)
        throw new Exception("this car belongs to other owner");

    c.setOwner(this);
    allCars.add(c);
}
```

The car sets its owner and sends itself to the Owner class' `addCar()` method, thats OK. However, why the Owner class' `addCar()` method sets the owner as itself **again** ?

I think there is a logical mistake. If you remove `c.setOwner(this)` line, it works fine.

Comment: Oh true. I didn't thought straight. But there is still a recursive problem. It is in toString. Because a toString of owners calls the toString of cars and the toString of car calls the owner toString again ..

Answer (score 0):

Usually adding element to a container should be done in the container itself. 
In you example `Owner` is the container and `Car` is the element.

As an example see `java.awt.Container` and `java.awt.Component`.

Don't call `owner.addCar(this);` from the `Car.setOwner`.

Let the `Owner` add the car to the list (which you already do) and set itself as owner to the `Car`.

```
public void setOwner(Owner owner) throws Exception{ 
    owner.addCar(this); //remove this line
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

Comment: if I remove addCar where do I add the car? I mean i just create a car but if I delete the code line I never call the function addCar

Comment: You already do it with `allCars.add(c);` in `Owner.addCar` method.

Comment: Yeah but I never call the function. Only creating an owner and car

Comment: Then why is it public. Do you want to add `Car` to `Owner` with both `Car.setOwner` and `Owner.addCar` methods or only with `Car.setOwner`?

Comment: Well it should be work on both ways. But the problem is already solved conserning adding but there is still a recursive problem in toString because they call each other all the time

Comment: Yes, because your `Car.toString` calls `Owner.toString` and `Owner.toString` in turn calls `Car.toString`. In your `Car.toString` change to this: `return "Car{" + "FGNr=" + FGNr + ", name=" + name + ", type=" + type + ", owner=" + owner.getName() + '}';`. Doing `", owner=" + owner` will call `Owner.toString`.

Comment: yeah but isn't it efficient if I like want to print every attribute of owner

Comment: Not really, name should be enough.

Comment: @tsotakp so the only way of avoiding recursion is to return every field?